# java swing component cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I took the following code from a tutorial:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class SwingGUI {

    public static void main( String[] args )
      {
        JFrame f = new JFrame( "test" );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        f.setSize( 1500, 900 );
        JLabel l = new JLabel( String.format( "%tT", new Date() ) );
        f.add(l);
        f.setVisible( true );
      }
}
```

The `f.add(l);` is highlighted and two errors are shown:

- The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JLabel)
- The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Being relatively new to java, I do not really understand what Eclipse is trying to tell me. What can I do to make it work?

edit: The code runs without the line `f.add(l);`, so the problem is not that JFrame or JLabel are not found. After fiddeling around a little I got rid of the first error, but the second still remains. The component cannot be resolved, because it is indirectly referenced. What does that mean?

Comment: Project-->Clean... ?

Comment: Clean up did not help. I set up a new project, chose jre1.8.0_31, created new package and class, and I still get error messages

Comment: Try deleting the import for java swing, then use control-shift-O in eclipse to have it find the JFrame class and import it.  The error message appears to say it cannot find JFrame; perhaps you copied the above from the example instead of your class and there's something misspelled.  If eclipse doesn't find anything, it means that the swing libraries are somehow not available to this eclipse project.

Comment: I tried ctrl-shift-o, but it does not help. The problem is not JFrame or JLabel in itself. The code runs without the `f.add(l);`

Comment: @arcy I tried "command+shift+O" on my mac and it worked, thanks for the help. I have been messing with this for an hour!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously the problem did not lie in the code, because it worked for everyone else. So I decided do remove and re-install java and eclipse, et voilà! Now it works. Thank you all for your feedback.

Answer (score 9):

Updating the execution environment under system library to JavaSE-1.7 or JavaSE-1.8 in eclipse should solve the problem.
To update the step below can be followed:

```
> Right-click on the project
> Select properties
> Java build path
> Library > Add Library > Add JRE SYSTEM Library
> Execution Environment
> Select JavaSE-1.7 or JavaSE-1.8
> Finish
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and found that my project was using the Java 8 libraries.
I installed the Java 7 library, added the same to the project properties by referencing the library from the installed `C:\Program Files\Java` folder and the error was gone.

Looks like, the new Java 8 version may a different way to resolve the swing component.

Comment: I am using jdk1.7.0_55, but have the same error. "Cannot cast MainFrame (extends JFrame) to JComponent" in Mac Eclipse.

Comment: For some weird reason, downgrading my project classpath JDK from Java 8 to Java 7 fixed it! Although the JToolBar class is available in all the newer JDKs I tried, including 8, 11, 15.

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing, but it matches the problem you describe:

This problem can arise when your own package contains a class that is called `JLabel`. The local class will then shadow the imported `JLabel`-class from the `javax.swing`-package and it might not have the same class-hierarchy as the original class.

To sum it up: it usaually is a bad idea to name ones own classes like existing JDK-classes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case for me. There is no local class, just the javax.swing.JLabel.

Comment: What is eclipse showing when you hover over the `JLabel` in your code?

Comment: javax.swing.JLabel and javax.swing.JLabel.JLabel(String arg0), respectively, depending on which JLabel I hover over. In addition, in both cases it shows "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found"

Answer (score 2):

I get this problem too.
unfortunately to resolve it I was needed to install my eclipse. but I think that the problem was **incompatibility between JRE and JAVA version in Eclipse**.

I used JRE supported JAVA8 when my project (and my eclipse indigo) can't upgrade to JAVA8. Updating to another eclipse that can support java 8 solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. There must be an installed (and selected) JDK in Eclipse:

   Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
2. The project must be configured to use that JDK:

   Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries
3. there should be an entry like "JRE System Library [JDK7]" in the list. If not press:

   Add Library... > JRE System Library
4. The project should have been created as a "Java Project":

   Project > Properties > Builders

   should include "Java Builder"

[SoCodeIt](http://socodeit.com)
[IDE Dr](https://idedr.com)

Answer (score 1):

am new here. I had this problem and it took me 2 days of research. I solved it by adding an external JAR file that contains all the required components to my Eclipse. Right-click project>>Buildpath>>Configure build path>> Add external JARS and browse for the JAR file on your computer. The JAR file can be downloaded here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsdgstubsjre15jar.htm
Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

The ***problem is not in code***.

It is due to JRE misconfiguration for project.
It may be due to **difference between the project's JRE and workspace's Jre.**

It may be solved by **Updating Eclipse or Jre...**

But from my side, I recommend you to do so..

> Goto **Window-->Preferences-->Java-->Installed JREs--->Execution Environments-->Select Project's JRE and *tick the perfect matching installed JRE*.**

If ***you have not a matching JRE download and add it in Installed JREs using Add Button.***

**At last, RESTART your Eclipse IDE.**
*This worked fine for me...*

*If it does not work, **UPDATE Eclipse***..

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem in eclipse IDE but after changing the jar file to  jre7(Right-click project>>Buildpath>>Configure build path>> AddLibrary>>Jre System Library) the error has resolved, i don't know how it happens can some one explain it.