# "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JTextField)" after using getContentPane() of JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I was messing around with javax.swing and noticed that I cannot set things (e.g. setSize for a JButton) at all! Here's a picture of what I mean:

[image: Image of code]

As you can see, I can't do things like "setText()" or "setSize()" or anything like that. Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: After typing in `textbox.setText("Testing")` it gives an error saying:

> The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

EDIT 2:

Somehow I've managed to make the setText work, however when I add it to the frame's contentPane using `frame.getContentPane().add(textbox);` This error pops up:

> The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JTextField)

EDIT 3:

This is Eclipse 3.3.2, which I'm using because of reasons.

EDIT 4:

The problem disappears when using Luna, the newest version. Thanks *so* much for *all* the help you've given me guys!

Comment: "It's not in the auto-complete list" is different from "I can't do it".

Comment: Ah, I apologize. When I type it in, however, it still does not work. I'll edit my post explaining a bit more :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582102/java-swing-component-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: @RyanJ Both solutions on that post don't work for me sadly :/

Comment: Can you open the JTextFrame add() method you are trying to call? Which JRE is the project compiling against? Are you sure you can use a 7+ year old Eclipse with it?