# Unable to add a JButton to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, addition

I am following this YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFQzFJqOSbA&index=83&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28) but I am getting add(lb) underlined in red with this error:

The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JButton)

I am confused because JButton extends Container according to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html does that not mean it is a valid parameter?

I feel like there is some stupid mistake I'm overlooking, help is appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Layout extends JFrame {
    private JButton lb;
    private JButton cb;
    private JButton rb;
    private FlowLayout layout;
    private Container container;

    public Layout() {
        super("title");
        layout = new FlowLayout();
        container = getContentPane();
        setLayout(layout);

        lb = new JButton("left");
        add(lb);
    }
}
```

When I mouse over lb = new JButton("left") the popup says this...

```
Open Declaration javax.swing.JButton.JButton(String arg0)
@ConstructorProperties(value={"text"})
```

Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

**Edit**

There's also an error on my import line that says

```
The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. 
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

here are screenshots of my project

[image: puu.sh/jBIt3/02a27cb22b.png]
[image: puu.sh/jBIuY/5a56f7426e.png]
[image: puu.sh/jBIvY/7b94dc5782.png]

Comment: 1) Please show the complete error message -- including the package-complete names of the offending classes. 2) Do you have another class in the same package named `JButton`?

Comment: Your code compiles on my IDE. Perhaps you should clean/rebuild your project.

Comment: I just noticed another error in my import lines. I don't know what you mean by package-complete names, I'll just screenshot my whole project.

http://puu.sh/jBIt3/02a27cb22b.png
.
http://puu.sh/jBIuY/5a56f7426e.png
.
http://puu.sh/jBIvY/7b94dc5782.png

I tried a clean, and also tried removing and readding the JRE library in the build path window

Comment: You should check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582102/java-swing-component-cannot-be-resolved) the answer that they provide point to a problem with their jdk

Comment: This has nothing to do with your program being wrong. something is wrong with your configured JRE in Eclipse. goto windows/preferences, then java/Installed JRE, remove the one you're using and add it again.

Comment: I'm still having trouble. I just reinstalled the JDK completely and it still doesn't work. I also tried using the JDK folder instead of JRE and that doesn't work either http://puu.sh/jBLji/3bc049acc7.png. Deleting the JRE folder and readding it also didn't work.

I also tried making a new project and copy pasting the code in and that didn't work.

Comment: Which eclipse are you using?

Comment: Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

Comment: Okay I just updated to Mars and my problem is fixed. I don't know how I ended up with Helios, I didn't install Eclipse that long ago, guess I clicked the wrong one. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Make sure to mark this question as resolved so it's up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled newer eclipse version.