# Cannot figure out Jcomponent error in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am trying to code a simple java program which simulates the roll of a dice. I think I have just about everything correct except for an error that I cannot figure out. I have searched this site and tried some of the answers given to others all to no avail. 
Tried so far: uninstall/reinstall Eclipse, 
adding `import javax.swing.JComponent`

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Randomnum {

public int[] math(int[]sum, int number1){
Random randomnumbers = new Random();
int a, b;
    for (a=0;a<number1;a++){
        int dice1 = 1 + randomnumbers.nextInt(6);
        int dice2 = 1 + randomnumbers.nextInt(1);
        b = dice1 + dice2;
        sum[a]=b;
    }
return sum;
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    String RollNumber;
    RollNumber = 
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Roll the Dice ");
    int number1;
    number1 = Integer.parseInt(RollNumber);
    int sum[]=new int [number1];
    int []arr = math(sum[],number1);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of each roll " +arr+ "number of roll "+number1 + "","Results" JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0);


}

private static int[] math(int i, int number1) {
    return null;
}
}
```

This is the error I am recieving:

> "The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Answer (score 0):

[[java swing component cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582102/java-swing-component-cannot-be-resolved][1])

The code ran for me once I fixed a few typos. You must have a configuration problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Like question linked above mentioned. I expect that the JRE installed isn't compatible because you should always have JComponent on the class path.

Comment: From the Run button click Run Configurations...
Click the classpath tab and verify that you have correct JRE System Library listed.

Comment: I have JRE 1.8.0_66 listed, I dled this version earlier as it was recommended to get Eclipse to open(ver. 3.5.2)